# apache httpd+mod_proxy+mod_ntlm

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, mod-proxy, mod-ntlm

Does anybody know of an open source solution that does HTTP proxying whilst providing NTLM authentication?
I've tried to set up apache + mod_proxy + mod_ntlm.
For HTTP GETs it works fine , i.e. the user is asked for a username+password and then the proxy retrieves the file.
However, for HTTP CONNECTs this does not work.
Remove mod_ntlm and apache + mod_proxy works fine with HTTP CONNECT.

Answer (score 1):

Squid proxy does support ntlm authentication. Check [this page](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Ntlm) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to authenticate client to proxy or to destination server? For proxy authentication (= Apache in your case) you just say

```
<Proxy *>
    AuthType NTLM
    ...
    Require valid-user
</Proxy>
```

and that will require clients to authenticate also when using `CONNECT`.